# Count the filtered data from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have 2 tables config_location_workstation and asset_workstation where both have the columns floor and workstation_number.

I want a query to return something like this :

FLOOR| SUM PRODUCTION WORKSTATION | SUM HEAD COUNT

This code below came from another source which I was able to pull up the sum but the numbers are incorrect because what I want to get is the number of all Production workstation.

```
SELECT config_location_workstation1.floor,
       (SELECT COUNT(config_location_workstation2.workstation_number)
        FROM config_location_workstation AS config_location_workstation2
        WHERE config_location_workstation2.floor = config_location_workstation1.floor) AS SUM_FLOOR,
       (SELECT COUNT(asset_workstation2.workstation_number)
        FROM asset_workstation AS asset_workstation2
        WHERE asset_workstation2.floor = config_location_workstation1.floor) AS SUM_HEAD
FROM config_location_workstation AS config_location_workstation1
INNER JOIN asset_workstation AS asset_workstation1
    ON (config_location_workstation1.workstation_number = asset_workstation1.workstation_number)
WHERE config_location_workstation1.workstation_name = 'NORTH PRODUCTION'
GROUP BY config_location_workstation1.floor
```

The problem is WHERE is not working on this code. 
The Workstation Column sum is invalid. It is pulling up all the entries. I only need to query all PRODUCTION workstations

Here's the current output.

```
+-------+-------------+------+------+
| Floor | Head Count  | Workstations|
+-------+-------------+------+------+
| 18TH  | 696         | 576         |
| 19TH  | 381         | 463         |
| 20TH  | 380         | 760         |
+-------+-------------+------+------+
```

Expected output for all Production workstations

```
+-------+-------------+------+------+
| Floor | Head Count  | Workstations|
+-------+-------------+------+------+
| 18TH  | 696         | 497         |
| 19TH  | 381         | 388         |
| 20TH  | 380         | 659         |
+-------+-------------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you could try using a subquery

```
select * from (
SELECT config_location_workstation1.floor,config_location_workstation1.workstation_name as z,
       (SELECT COUNT(config_location_workstation2.workstation_number)
        FROM config_location_workstation AS config_location_workstation2
        WHERE config_location_workstation2.floor = config_location_workstation1.floor) AS SUM_FLOOR,
       (SELECT COUNT(asset_workstation2.workstation_number)
        FROM asset_workstation AS asset_workstation2
        WHERE asset_workstation2.floor = config_location_workstation1.floor) AS SUM_HEAD
FROM config_location_workstation AS config_location_workstation1
INNER JOIN asset_workstation AS asset_workstation1
    ON (config_location_workstation1.workstation_number = asset_workstation1.workstation_number)
GROUP BY config_location_workstation1.floor
) x
WHERE z = 'NORTH PRODUCTION'
```

**UPDATE:**

```
select x.*,y.* from ( SELECT *, COUNT(workstation_name) as COUNT_FLOOR 
FROM config_location_workstation WHERE workstation_name LIKE '%PRODUCTION%' GROUP BY floor)x 
join 
(SELECT *, COUNT(floor) as COUNT_USERS FROM asset_workstation GROUP BY floor) y on 
x.workstation_number = y.workstation_number
```

Comment: you mean no results at all?

Comment: Can you comment the first and the last 2 lines and execute the query? after that can you check what results do you get in the Z column

Comment: Followed your instruction on commenting out those lines and I got duplicate results with same numbers the results for z is the all the workstation names in the config_location_workstation column.

Comment: Is there a more simplified query for getting the total count for two tables that also has a filtered call? mean, I can call ONLY the production workstations.

Comment: did your Z column have 'NORTH PRODUCTION' in it?

Comment: Cause your query seems to be fine just that it might not have North Production in it. Or probably there is an extra white space in it towards the end

Comment: Yes there is. So to better understand my query I separated my tables..

Comment: Here's for the first table `SELECT *, COUNT(workstation_name) as COUNT_FLOOR FROM config_location_workstation WHERE workstation_name LIKE '%PRODUCTION%' GROUP BY floor`

Comment: Here's the 2nd table `SELECT *, COUNT(floor) as COUNT_USERS FROM asset_workstation GROUP BY floor` I just need to combine that two tables. but the results should be the same.

Comment: Do these 2 tables have a column in common?

Comment: Yes. The workstation_number. in config_location_workstation it is the database of all the workstation numbers and for the asset_workstation it is the database of users with their workstation numbers.

Comment: ok so you could do something like this then
`select * from ( SELECT *, COUNT(workstation_name) as COUNT_FLOOR FROM config_location_workstation WHERE workstation_name LIKE '%PRODUCTION%' GROUP BY floor)x 
join 
SELECT *, COUNT(floor) as COUNT_USERS FROM asset_workstation GROUP BY floor
on x.workstation_number = asset_workstation.workstation_number`

Comment: I'm getting errors on this one.
`Unrecognized keyword. (near "COUNT" at position 173)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 178)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "floor" at position 179)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 184)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 186)
Unexpected token. (near "COUNT_USERS" at position 189)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "FROM" at position 201)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "FROM" at position 201)`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Try this
`select x.*,y.*  from ( SELECT *, COUNT(workstation_name) as COUNT_FLOOR FROM config_location_workstation WHERE workstation_name LIKE '%PRODUCTION%' GROUP BY floor)x join (SELECT *, COUNT(floor) as COUNT_USERS FROM asset_workstation GROUP BY floor) y on x.workstation_number = asset_workstation.workstation_number`

Comment: We are almost there @Standin.Wolf. getting an error now Unknown column 'asset_workstation.floor' in 'on clause'. I don't know why it's getting an error message that the column in unknown.

Comment: `select x.*,y.* from ( SELECT *, COUNT(workstation_name) as COUNT_FLOOR FROM config_location_workstation WHERE workstation_name LIKE '%PRODUCTION%' GROUP BY floor)x join (SELECT *, COUNT(floor) as COUNT_USERS FROM asset_workstation GROUP BY floor) y on x.workstation_number = y.workstation_number`

Comment: I changed the asset_workstation to y and it is not showing any results as well.

Comment: I hope there is a column called workstation_number in both the tables

Comment: It's working now @Standin.Wolf. I changed the on x.workstation_number = y.workstation_number to floor. and Everything looks good now!

Comment: Awesome. I have updated the answer. You can mark it correct